# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str' how do i go from str to bytes

Tags: python, sockets, udp

code for the client side

```
from socket import *

serverName = "192.168.32.100"

serverPort = 12345

clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)

i = 1


while (i<= 5) :

message = (input('enter grade to be submitted 
to the server : '))

clientSocket.sendto(message,(serverName, 
serverPort))

modifiedMessage, serverAddress = 
clientSocket.recvfrom(2048)

print( modifiedMessage)

i = i + 1

clientSocket.close()
```

code for the server side

```
from socket import *
serverPort = 12345
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSocket.bind(('', serverPort))
print ("the server is ready to receive grades")

while 1 :

message,clientAddress = 
serverSocket.recvfrom(2048)

if message >= 0 and  message < 49 :
    modifiedMessage = 'F'
elif message > 49  and message <= 70:
    modifiedMessage = 'C'
elif message > 70 and message <=80:
    modifiedMessage = 'B'
elif message > 80 and message <= 100:
    modifiedMessage = 'A'
else :
    modifiedMessage = 'invalid mark'
serverSocket.sendto( modifiedMessage , 
clientAddress)
```

this is the code
can it be solved without encoding?
problem seem to be from this line  clientSocket.sendto(message,(serverName, serverPort))
new to python not sure how to go about solving this problem

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your string `message` into an array of bytes. You can do this by wrapping `message` in the `bytes` function when you call `.sendto`:

```
clientSocket.sendto(bytes(message, 'utf-8'),(serverName, 
serverPort))
```